# Send asana user Id and Password through a server request and get the APIKey in response

Tags: ios, asana

Hi All: I have integrated my ios app with asana and for the user authentication I am using asana APIKey which is a 32 characters long string (capital/small alphabets plus digits and a dot),so when ever the user wants to access his/her asana account he/she has to enter the APIKey into a text field,which is kind of frustrating.I want to know if this is or may become possible that the user enter his/her id and password and the app send it to the server through a server request and return asana APIKey of that particular user in response

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the best answer (as I think your other question on SO indicates) is probably to use OAuth if it's feasible. Especially on mobile clients, typing a long API key is a huge pain, which was a big motivator for adding OAuth support (http://blog.asana.com/2013/04/introducing-asana-connect/).